# Canceling a title edit doesn't ask for confirmation

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, editor, cancel

I was editing a question and started from the title. Then when editing question body I accidentally pressed "Esc" instead of "`" for code formatting (body wasn't edited yet). The edit was closed without any prompt to cancel and I lost the edits in the title.

I was on Chrome version 33.0.1750.146.

I suppose this is a bug and there should have been a prompt asking if I want to abandon the edit.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox.

Comment: From playing about with this (admittedly on mobile in desktop mode) it seems that both clicking esc and clicking "Cancel" both insta-cancel when only the title is edited. On the other hand if the body is edited then a confirmation box is shown when clicking cancel

Comment: Cannot repro on Chrome

Comment: @qwertynl, I've encountered the bug on Chrome version 33.0.1750.146.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on Chrome 33, Windows 7 either. When I'm on edit page, pressing "Esc" button didn't do anything at all. I wonder if there's something else causing this...

Comment: @superM did you change the body as well? Looks like the warning is displayed only if you changed something in the post body.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I changed only the title. That's the issue that nothing was prompted when I tried to closed the edit.

Comment: I see, so the "when editing question body" part is misleading. So to reproduce one has to only change the title then press ESC, to see the title edit vaporized into thin air. Can you edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: reproduced, fix incoming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.3.11.2031` on meta and `2014.3.11.1435` on sites.

Comment: What about tags? When editing a question and changing tags only, ESC will silently cancel the edit too without any warning. In my opinion tags are as important as title, so... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard of course that was also taken care of too, but this should be fairly rare, since the ESC button doesn't trigger edit  cancellation when the tag editor is focused.

Comment: Awesome! Same build, or will it wait for 2014.3.11.2032 and 2014.3.11.1436?

Comment: same change-set even

Comment: Cool, hope this isn't the change causing the readonly mode! ;)